# convert a negative number to positive without affecting decimal points in js

Tags: javascript

I need to convert a negative number to a positive number. My attempt is as below.

```
Math.abs(-4.0);
```

It will return 4 as the answer. But I need 4.0 as the answer. Here I don't know the decimal places to be set. For different numbers, there's a different decimal point value. Actually, that will totally depend on the web socket output. According to the input value, the server-side defined different floating points which there's not any pattern according to our requirement.

So in js, is there any better way to handle this without getting decimal places separately?

Comment: numbers in javascript only show as many decimals as required ... `-4.0` would just be `-4` ... if you need a string with a certain number of digits, use, `.toFixed` - but note, this will result in a **string**

Comment: Here I don't know the decimal places to be set. For different numbers, there's a different decimal point value. Actually, that will totally depend on the service response. According to the input value, the service side defined different floating points which there's not any pattern according to our requirement.

Comment: so the output decimal places depends on the input decimal places? - unfortunately javascript considers a values like `4.0`, `4.00`, `4.00000` to have zero decimal places - you'll need to create a function that takes a second argument being the number of decimal places ... so `const abs = (n, d) => Math.abs(n).toFixed(d)` then call it with the number of decimal places required for output as the second argument

Comment: simpler still, just make sure where you output a value that needs to show decimal places, use `.toFixed(x)` there, because you'd know how many decimal places you want in your output

Comment: what do you want to achieve anyway? if you want to preserve the precision, then nothing should be done to the resulting number. But if you care more about formatting, then the best you can do is to use toFixed() and define a rather constant decimal precision and stick to it.

Comment: This issue occurred only for numbers like 4.0, 4.00 which are having zero decimal places. It was worked fine for 4.1, 4.13 which are having non zero decimal points. So in javascript is there not any way to handle this issue directly?

Comment: is this just for display purposes? the builtin `Intl.NumberFormat` object can help you with that, and can handle contextual situations like currencies. You still have to specify the number of significant digits or decimals in precision but you can give it ranges of length in some situations.

Comment: it really depends on the code that is using the result - yes, there's ways to handle the issue directly ... but you'll need to change the code that you haven't shown - also, `4.10` has one decimal place not two - so it's not just `4.0` and `4.00` that will trip your code up

Comment: the only way to preserve an unknown number of decimal places on input to output, is if you use strings to store the value - but that just shifts the problem to where you would be creating those strings from an unknown number of decimal places - somewhere in your code, the number of decimal places needs to be "known" - otherwise you are fighting a losing battle

Comment: alternatively, convert the number to a string, and count the number of values after the `.` if one is there. `x.toString().match(/(\.)(\d*)$/)`. group 2's length will be the number of decimals to preserve if there is a decimal value, otherwise it'd be null

Comment: @Derek - `4.0000.toString()` becomes .... ?

Comment: @JaromandaX good point, it strips the insignificant digits when converting. looks like Intl.NumberFormat is probably the best bet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in other comments, you won't be able to keep the precision. `toFixed()` is definitely not a solution and this problem has valid case scenarios.

We had to do something similar where teachers would input a grade (90.05) and were expected to keep the same number of decimals for all their students inside of a single gradebook. Teachers grade differently depending of the situation:

```
Teacher A | Teacher B | Teacher C
   90          90.5       4.95
   80          88.5       3.80
   75          80.0       5.00
```

One way to solve this, especially if the request comes as a string (from an input, http request, etc.), is to maintain the number as a string and return a string value.

Note that this is a very crude implementation (our implementation is more fail-safe), but the idea is simple:

```js
function absString(n) {
  numberString = n.toString();
  if (numberString[0] === '-') {
    return numberString.substring(1);
  }
  else {
    return numberString;
  }
}

console.log(absString('-1'));
console.log(absString('-2.0'));
console.log(absString('2.0'));
console.log(absString('-0.57'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the number `toFixed` method as follows:

```js
var decimalPlaces = 5 // Change this to change the number of decimals

console.log(Math.abs(-4.0).toFixed(decimalPlaces))
```

Comment: Here I don't know the decimal places to be set. For different numbers, there's a different decimal point value. Actually, that will totally depend on the service response. According to the input value, the service side defined different floating points which there's not any pattern according to our requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for display purposes only you can use the [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat) object to format your value appropriately. Example:

```
Intl.NumberFormat(
  undefined,
  { signDisplay: 'never', minimumSignificantDigits: 3, maximumSignificantDigits: 20 }
).format(-4.06364635454000); // "4.06364635454"
Intl.NumberFormat(
  undefined,
  { signDisplay: 'never', minimumSignificantDigits: 1, maximumSignificantDigits: 20 }
).format(-4.0); // "4"
Intl.NumberFormat(
  undefined,
  { signDisplay: 'never', style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }
).format(-4.06364635454000); // "€4.06"
```